# echo the before year and month using a function in php?

Tags: php

i am a newbie of php, supposed my blog created on 2011 year  1 month.and the article stored time as this `1305357473`. now i want to use a function, which can output the before year and moth as this.

```
2011 year  1 month
2011 year  2 month
2011 year  3 month
2011 year  4 month
2011 year  5 month
......
```

i want to make the function can output the current and the past year and month.
this is my function and output the result. but i don't know how to finish.

```
function outYearMonth($year,$month){
    $year=date(Y);
    $past_month=strtotime(date(1)) ; 
    $month=strtotime(date(m)); 

    $jg_month=round($month - $past_month);

    $month=array();
    for($i==0;$i<=$jg_month;$i++){
        $month[]= date(1)+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I can't understand what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: try date('Y',$ts) . ' year, ' . date('m',$ts) . ' month'; ok? (where $ts is your 130535...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
$months = 10; //count of months 
$date = date_create( 'now' );
echo date_format( $date, 'Y M' );
for ( $i = 0; $i < $months; $i++ ) {
    date_sub( $date , date_interval_create_from_date_string( '1 months' ) );
    echo date_format( $date, 'Y M' );
}
```

Will output:

```
2011 May
2011 Apr
2011 Mar
2011 Feb
2011 Jan
2010 Dec
2010 Nov
2010 Oct
2010 Sep
2010 Aug
2010 Jul
```

Comment: I have updated script to output a number of months you need in desc format

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date('Y m');
```

will give you this year and month

```
echo date('Y m',strtotime('last month',time()))
```

will give you last month

for looping through all the month just get the current month and make a loop

```
$currentMonth = (int) date('m',time());
$currentYear = date('Y',time());

for($i=0; $i <= $currentMonth; $i++) {
    echo "$currentYear $i";
}
```

will echo all months

```
2011 1

2011 2

2011 3

2011 4

2011 5
```

Comment: if the year is any year it will still work, there is no dependency

Comment: if i want to set a begin month and year to it? how should i do? maybe my blog created on 2010  10

Comment: oh, if i want to 2010 12, 2011 1.....2012 1 your code can't do that? how to do the date style like i said?